# Duplicate timezone with different name

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

According to the timezone information returned by `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`

```
foreach (var tmp in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", tmp.Id, tmp.BaseUtcOffset);
}
```

There are two timezones that look very similar:

```
E. Australia Standard Time: 10:00:00
AUS Eastern Standard Time: 10:00:00
```

`AUS Eastern Standard Time` is AEST...but what is `E. Australia Standard Time`?  There is no mention of this timezone on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Time).

What is the difference from these timezones?  Is `E. Australia Standard Time` a non-standard and unfamiliar name?

Comment: From the Wikipedia article the eastern time zone is split into 2, the north half does not have DST it is +10 hrs all the time. Not sure which is which.

Comment: *ALL* `TimeZoneInfo.Id` values should be treated as suspect.  Their only purpose is to act as a unique identifier, matching the corresponding registry key.  See more examples in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your test to

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", tmp.Id, tmp.BaseUtcOffset, 
                                  tmp.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
```

`E. Australia Standard Time` does not support DST and is tagged as "Brisbane" which is in the east but does not use DST.